# LdapConnection SearchRequest throwing object does not exist error

Tags: exception, search, ldap

I am trying to query an LDAP server to find an LDAP user and import it into my system.  However, when I try to do this, the request throws a `DirectoryOperationException`, saying `The object does not exist`.

```
ldapConnection.AuthType = AuthType.Negotiate;

if (ldapDomain.UseEncryption)
{
    ldapConnection.SessionOptions.SecureSocketLayer = true;
    ldapConnection.SessionOptions.StartTransportLayerSecurity(null);
}

var credentials = new NetworkCredential(loginName, password, ldapDomain.Name);
ldapConnection.Bind(credentials);

var filter = String.Format("(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(anr={0})(!(UserAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2)))", loginName);
var request = new SearchRequest(containerDistinguishedName, filter, SearchScope.Subtree);
var response = ldapConnection.SendRequest(request) as SearchResponse;
var entry = response.Entries[0];
```

I only have to work against a Microsoft/Windows LDAP server.  Right now, `containerDistinguishedName` is empty, but could be filled in with values to further restrict the search filter.

Comment: From the looks of this, an empty `containerDistinguishedName` refers to the Root DSE, but a subtree scoped search should still work, assuming the authorization state of the connection permits trawling the DIT. Try using the base object that "tops" the DIT for `containerDistinguishedName`, something like `dc=example,dc=com`

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation, had tried that, but to no avail.  Not sure what happened, but eventually the request stopped throwing the error.  I will review the changelogs to see what may have remedied the situation.

Comment: Addendum: the error popped back up, and sure enough, the empty `containerDistinguishedName` was the culprit.  Found a way to get around it by getting the DC components off of the ldap connection

Comment: Excellent; good thinking.

Comment: Terry, would you mind putting your comment here as the answer? :)

Comment: I have  put my comment here as the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the looks of this, an empty `containerDistinguishedName` refers to the Root DSE, but a `subtree`scoped search should still work, assuming the authorization state of the connection permits trawling the DIT (the Root DSE is only returned in the search result if the search sole was `base`). Try using the base object that "tops" the DIT for `containerDistinguishedName`, something like `dc=example,dc=com`.

#### see also

- [LDAP: Search best practices](http://www.ldapguru.info/ldap/ldap-search-best-practices.html)
- [LDAP: Programming practices](http://www.ldapguru.info/ldap/ldap-programming-practices.html)