# LdapConnection SearchRequest throwing object does not exist error - revisited

Tags: c#, winforms, exception, search, ldap

I have the same question as in [LdapConnection SearchRequest throwing object does not exist error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20220651/ldapconnection-searchrequest-throwing-object-does-not-exist-error). The answer over there doesn't seem to work for me.

Whenever these two lines of code are executed (Winforms app, C#)...

```
var request = new SearchRequest(DN, "(objectClass=*)", SearchScope.Subtree, null);
var response = (SearchResponse)LdapConnection.SendRequest(request);
```

...*and* `DN` points to an existing distinguished name, everything works fine.
If `DN` does not point to an existing distinguished name, I get an "Object does not exist" error instead of a valid `SearchResponse` object with `.Entries.Count == 0`.
I cannot change the *filter* parameter, this has to be `"(objectClass=*)"` (in case that would make any difference; it is different the Stackoverflow post that I refer to).

Anyone any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's expected behaviour.

The DN you're providing is the search root: the location in the directory to start the search. If that is invalid, then it can't perform the search, which is why you get an exception.

That is different than a case where the search is successfully performed, but no results are found.

If you can't verify ahead of time if the DN exists, then just catch that exception.

Comment: Okay. I indeed cannot verify ahead of time if the DN exists, so catching the exception it is. Thank you Gabriel.